# Returning a collection inside of an IEnumerable method

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

The following scenario came out of a discussion I was having with a fellow developer on this project. He likes to execute an `Ienumerable` as soon as possible, hence why he’s doing it inside of the method. Whereas, I’m thinking that if you wait until the object is actually needed, using differed execution, you’re eliminating wasted objects in the memory.

Knowing that `PricingInformation` is a `List`, is my return statement consider best practice or not? Should I defer the execution to a later time? Or is it wise to `ToArray()` the `Select` during the return statement?

Which of these approaches do you guys think is more appropriate?

```
public IEnumerable<ProductPrice> GetPrices(IEnumerable<string> skus, string accountNumber)
{
    if (skus.Any())
    {
        TesscoModel.PricingQuery priceQuery = new TesscoModel.PricingQuery();
        foreach (string sku in skus)
            priceQuery.Skus.Add(new TesscoModel.SkuDetail() { Sku = sku, Quantity = 1 });
        priceQuery.Account = accountNumber;
        TesscoModel.PricingInformationBatch pricingInfoBatch = RestHelper.PostJsonAsync<TesscoModel.PricingInformationBatch>(Settings.PricingServiceEndpoint, priceQuery).Result;

        return pricingInfoBatch?.PricingInformation?.Select(pi => new ProductPrice { Sku = pi.Sku, Price = pi.OnSalePrice != default(decimal) ? pi.OnSalePrice : pi.UnitPrice, ListPrice = pi.ListPrice })?.ToArray() ?? Enumerable.Empty<ProductPrice>();
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ProductPrice>();
    }
}
```

This method then gets called by another method inside of a `helper`. Inside of which, I am using `FirstOrDefault` to find the first `sku`. `FirstOrDefault` is again an `enumerator`.

I think the differed execution is more appropriate here, because I shouldn't execute the pointer until I absolutely have to. I'm thinking that by using `ToArray()` too early, I'm keeping the object on memory for too long. Even though, it might not be needed.

```
//Get sku Pricing in bulk
IEnumerable<ProductPrice> productPrices = productService.GetPrices(skus, (!account.IsNull()) ? account.AccountNumber : string.Empty);

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var productPrice = productPrices.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Sku.Equals(line.Sku));
    line.ListPrice = productPrice?.ListPrice ?? default(decimal);
    line.YourPrice = productPrice?.Price ?? default(decimal);
}
```

Comment: Your question is about to get closed due to lack of context - perhaps you could provide some more information, such as how and where this method will be used, and why you think deferred execution could be beneficial here?

Comment: The question was edited to provide more context, it is probably fine to withdraw close votes now.

Comment: @t3chb0t I updated the question. Hopefully, you’ll change you mind.

Answer (score 1):

#### There is no 0 and 1 answer

> X likes to execute an `IEnumerable` as soon as possible, hence why X is doing it inside of the method.

Whereas

> Y is thinking that if you wait until the object is actually needed, using differed execution, you’re eliminating wasted objects in the memory.

They are both wrong. The answer isn't digital, this is, there is no 0 or 1 answer. It depends. Sometimes you must execute a collection and return a non-`IEnumerable`.

#### Materialize when working with databases

Such a case would be querying a database. In this scenario you'd open a database connection (or create a context if it's some ORM) and dispose it at the end. If you don't execute it with `ToList` or `ToArray` etc. you won't be able to do it later. The runtime would wrap your enumerator with an anonymous type containing the context but when the execution leaves the method, the context gets disposed and it'll throw an excepiton the moment you try to get the data. In this situation you should return a non-`IEnumerable` type.

The reason the return type shouldn't be an `IEnumerable` in this case is that `IEnumerable` tells me that the return type is lazy so if I wanted to use it multiple times I'd call `ToList` myslef (again) to get the result which would unnecessrily enumerate the collection again.

So, the bottom line is: if you don't have to materialize the result (because you won't be able to get it later when the service/provider is disposed etc), don't do it but be consistent with the API (return types).

---

When the result value it's materialized I expect you to communicate this fact clearly by using `ICollection`, `IList` or anything else but `IEnumerable`.

---

#### Materialize for easier debugging when calling resources

As far as your code is concerned you call a web-service there

> ```
> RestHelper.PostJsonAsync(..)
> ```

So you should ask yourself: Is it ok to be done multiple times if someone else uses `Any` and then starts enumerating it again or is better to prevent such situations (for whatever reason)?

I would use `IList` here for one more reason: it's quite difficult to debug lazy code that is calling web-services, databases or other resources. When something goes wrong here you'll be having a lot of *fun*.

---

#### Consider materialized parameters

The same priciples apply to parameters. In your example you execute `skus` multiple times: with `Any` and with the `foreach` loop.

Here, I'd requested an `ICollection` or an `IList` to tell the caller: *Look out! I'll be using your collection more then once* (so you might consider materializing it for better performance before givit it to me).

Answer (score 1):

#### Readability

You tend to cram a lot of code into very few lines. Some lines are just too long and complex, in my opinion. There's several things that I would do differently:

- `var` lets you remove duplicate type name occurrences.
- `""` is more succinct than `string.Empty`. The same goes for `0m` versus `default(decimal)`. Personally, I much prefer `""` and `0m`, not just because they're shorter, but also because their actual value is immediately recognizable.
- For long method calls, you may want to put each argument on a line of its own.
- For chained (Linq) method calls, you may want to put each method call on a separate line.
- Ternary ifs aren't terribly readable, especially not when the same line also contains both Elvis and null coalescing operators. Another reason to split things up into multiple lines.
- Many of the classes involved appear to be missing useful constructors. Not only does that require more writing, it also makes it easy to create invalid objects (I assume that a `SkuDetail` object without a `Sku` isn't valid, for example?). If you like writing out property names for clarity's sake, that's also possible with argument names.
- Why do you write out the `TesscoModel` namespace (or outer class?) prefix everywhere?

#### Other notes

- You can introduce an early return by changing `if (skus.Any())` into `if (!skus.Any())`, which should make the rest of the method a little easier to read (less indentation levels, no edge-case handling afterwards).
- Are you sure `GetPrices` shouldn't be an `async` method? Fetching a `Result` like that will block the current thread untill the result is available.
- Using `default(decimal)` (or just `0`) to indicate 'has no value' looks quite brittle to me. It's easy to forget a check like that, and doing so might cause products to be given away for free (price = 0)... Using a `decimal?` instead lets you clearly signal that there may not be a value, and it forces calling code to check for that.

#### Deferred execution

As for your question, in this particular case deferred execution actually has a negative impact. Each time you iterate the result (which `FirstOrDefault` does) `Select` has to do work again - not just for the first matching item, but for all preceding ones as well. That work has to be repeated for each next `FirstOrDefault` call, and since the results aren't cached anywhere that likely means that a lot of the work will go to waste.

For example, if there's one sku per line, then instead of `n` you end up with `(n^2 + n) / 2` `ProductPrice` objects being created. That's quadratic rather than linear!

Materializing the results immediately doesn't suffer from that problem. But if you expect a lot of skus then it's probably better to create a dictionary that maps skus to `ProductPrice` objects. It'll take more work than creating an array, but lookups will take constant rather than linear time, so you end up with a more scalable solution.